# How to specify a package source for nuget

Tags: nuget, syncfusion, nuget-package-restore

We are currently using SyncFusion for our solution at work for one of our solutions. In local every package are restoring but in VSTS it seem that it's having some difficulties to mix both syncfusion packages with official nuget packages.

I posted the entire log of the nuget restore on a gist here : https://gist.github.com/erickgirard/844f57d0f98f0cbea13d6ad4ddbde7e0

What I believe is that for every package in `packages.config` it's trying all sources (is there a possibility to specify a source for one package?)

Not quite sure of what are the solution here beside commiting the syncfusion dlls in the source control.

Here is the nuget.config file of the solution:

```
<configuration>
    <solution>
        <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />
    </solution>
    <packageSources>
        <add key="sync fusion nuget feed" value="http://nuget.syncfusion.com/aspnetmvc" />
    </packageSources>
    <packageRestore>
        <add key="enabled" value="True" />
    </packageRestore>
</configuration>
```

Here is an excerpt of the logs:

```
[...]
2017-10-16T16:10:33.6063822Z Acquiring lock for the installation of Swashbuckle.Core 5.5.3
2017-10-16T16:10:33.6123760Z Acquired lock for the installation of Swashbuckle.Core 5.5.3
2017-10-16T16:10:33.6123760Z Installing Swashbuckle.Core 5.5.3.
2017-10-16T16:10:33.6173723Z   NotFound http://nuget.syncfusion.com/nuget_aspnetmvc/nuget/getsyncfusionpackages/aspnetmvc/Packages(Id='System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt',Version='5.1.4') 97ms
2017-10-16T16:10:33.6173723Z   GET http://nuget.syncfusion.com/nuget_aspnetmvc/nuget/getsyncfusionpackages/aspnetmvc/FindPackagesById()?id='System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt'
2017-10-16T16:10:33.6453473Z   NotFound http://nuget.syncfusion.com/nuget_aspnetmvc/nuget/getsyncfusionpackages/aspnetmvc/Packages(Id='Microsoft.Net.Compilers',Version='2.2.0') 562ms
2017-10-16T16:10:33.6453473Z   GET http://nuget.syncfusion.com/nuget_aspnetmvc/nuget/getsyncfusionpackages/aspnetmvc/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.Net.Compilers'
2017-10-16T16:10:33.6913056Z   OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.identitymodel.tokens.jwt/5.1.4/system.identitymodel.tokens.jwt.5.1.4.nupkg 143ms
2017-10-16T16:10:33.6913056Z Acquiring lock for the installation of System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt 5.1.4
2017-10-16T16:10:33.6923050Z Acquired lock for the installation of System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt 5.1.4
2017-10-16T16:10:33.6923050Z Installing System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt 5.1.4.
2017-10-16T16:10:33.6923050Z   NotFound http://nuget.syncfusion.com/nuget_aspnetmvc/nuget/getsyncfusionpackages/aspnetmvc/Packages(Id='Unity.AspNet.WebApi',Version='4.0.1') 103ms
2017-10-16T16:10:33.6923050Z   GET http://nuget.syncfusion.com/nuget_aspnetmvc/nuget/getsyncfusionpackages/aspnetmvc/FindPackagesById()?id='Unity.AspNet.WebApi'
2017-10-16T16:10:33.6943020Z   OK http://nuget.syncfusion.com/nuget_aspnetmvc/nuget/getsyncfusionpackages/aspnetmvc/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.Net.Compilers' 49ms
2017-10-16T16:10:33.7092888Z   OK http://nuget.syncfusion.com/nuget_aspnetmvc/nuget/getsyncfusionpackages/aspnetmvc/FindPackagesById()?id='Unity.AspNet.WebApi' 44ms
2017-10-16T16:10:33.7312690Z   OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/unity.aspnet.webapi/4.0.1/unity.aspnet.webapi.4.0.1.nupkg 170ms
[...]
2017-10-16T16:10:41.1345069Z Completed installation of System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt 5.1.4
2017-10-16T16:10:41.1395038Z Adding package 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.5.1.4' to folder 'd:\a\3\s\Projets\packages'
2017-10-16T16:10:41.1425014Z Added package 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.5.1.4' to folder 'd:\a\3\s\Projets\packages'
2017-10-16T16:10:41.1455002Z Added package 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.5.1.4' to folder 'd:\a\3\s\Projets\packages' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json'
2017-10-16T16:10:41.3558804Z Completed installation of Swashbuckle.Core 5.5.3
2017-10-16T16:10:41.3578871Z Completed installation of Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client 15.115.0-preview
2017-10-16T16:10:41.3578871Z Adding package 'Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client.15.115.0-preview' to folder 'd:\a\3\s\Projets\packages'
2017-10-16T16:10:41.3588793Z Adding package 'Swashbuckle.Core.5.5.3' to folder 'd:\a\3\s\Projets\packages'
2017-10-16T16:10:41.4116910Z Added package 'Swashbuckle.Core.5.5.3' to folder 'd:\a\3\s\Projets\packages'
2017-10-16T16:10:41.4116910Z Added package 'Swashbuckle.Core.5.5.3' to folder 'd:\a\3\s\Projets\packages' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json'
2017-10-16T16:10:41.4116910Z Added package 'Swashbuckle.Core.5.5.3' to folder 'd:\a\3\s\Projets\packages'
2017-10-16T16:10:41.4116910Z Added package 'Swashbuckle.Core.5.5.3' to folder 'd:\a\3\s\Projets\packages' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json'
[...]
2017-10-16T16:10:56.8833741Z Running restore with 2 concurrent jobs.
2017-10-16T16:10:56.8853733Z Reading project file d:\a\3\s\Projets\DobermanHub.GFI.Functions\DobermanHub.GFI.Functions.csproj.
2017-10-16T16:10:56.9003673Z Restoring packages for d:\a\3\s\Projets\DobermanHub.GFI.Functions\DobermanHub.GFI.Functions.csproj...
2017-10-16T16:10:56.9153620Z Restoring packages for .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1...
2017-10-16T16:10:57.0043336Z   GET http://nuget.syncfusion.com/aspnetmvc/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions'
2017-10-16T16:10:57.0203252Z   GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.net.sdk.functions/index.json
2017-10-16T16:10:57.0992975Z   OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.net.sdk.functions/index.json 85ms
2017-10-16T16:10:57.1122942Z   InternalServerError http://nuget.syncfusion.com/aspnetmvc/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions' 111ms
2017-10-16T16:10:57.1162923Z Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'http://nuget.syncfusion.com/aspnetmvc/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions''.
2017-10-16T16:10:57.1162923Z Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).
2017-10-16T16:10:57.1162923Z   GET http://nuget.syncfusion.com/aspnetmvc/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions'
2017-10-16T16:10:57.1332855Z   GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.net.sdk.functions/1.0.2/microsoft.net.sdk.functions.1.0.2.nupkg
2017-10-16T16:10:57.1442827Z   OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.net.sdk.functions/1.0.2/microsoft.net.sdk.functions.1.0.2.nupkg 10ms
2017-10-16T16:10:57.1762708Z   InternalServerError http://nuget.syncfusion.com/aspnetmvc/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions' 59ms
2017-10-16T16:10:57.1762708Z Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'http://nuget.syncfusion.com/aspnetmvc/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions''.
2017-10-16T16:10:57.1762708Z Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).
2017-10-16T16:10:57.1762708Z   GET http://nuget.syncfusion.com/aspnetmvc/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions'
2017-10-16T16:10:57.3411621Z   InternalServerError http://nuget.syncfusion.com/aspnetmvc/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions' 165ms
2017-10-16T16:10:59.6996347Z System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.FatalProtocolException: Failed to retrieve information about 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions' from remote source 'http://nuget.syncfusion.com/aspnetmvc/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions''. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).
2017-10-16T16:10:59.6996347Z    at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
2017-10-16T16:10:59.6996347Z    at NuGet.Protocol.HttpSource.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`1.<<GetAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
2017-10-16T16:10:59.6996347Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2017-10-16T16:10:59.7006128Z    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
2017-10-16T16:10:59.7006128Z    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
2017-10-16T16:10:59.7006128Z    at NuGet.Common.ConcurrencyUtilities.<ExecuteWithFileLockedAsync>d__2`1.MoveNext()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In our NuGet Server, we are maintaining multiple Feeds based on platforms and in NuGet site we are displaying friendly feed URLs. If you copy and paste those friendly URLs in any browser, it will redirect to actual Feed Link.

Friendly Feed URL:
http://nuget.syncfusion.com/aspnetmvc/

Actual Feed URL:
http://nuget.syncfusion.com/nuget_aspnetmvc/nuget/getsyncfusionpackages/aspnetmvc/

Your given below URL is incorrect hence it’s return 500 error while resorting the ASPNET MVC package.

http://nuget.syncfusion.com/aspnetmvc/FindPackagesById()?id=%27Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions%27

In your case, you must use actual feed URL instead of friendly URL.

http://nuget.syncfusion.com/nuget_aspnetmvc/nuget/getsyncfusionpackages/aspnetmvc/FindPackagesById()?id=%27Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions%27

Please follow the steps given in the below link.
https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/7609/how-to-install-syncfusion-nuget-packages-in-visual-studio-2017

Thanks,
Mathan Kumar

Comment: Oh that is good to know! Interestingly enough, the friendly url can work as part of Visual Studio nuget settings..